# How to achieve a scrolling upwards effect, while parts of prev-text still in view

Tags: javascript, css

I'm aiming to recreate an animation using JavaScript and CSS. It involves a list of words from a CMS, where the quantity of a single word can change. The goal is to create an endless vertical scrolling effect without a visible loop restart, similar to a marquee. I'm struggling with modifying my code to achieve the desired behavior. CSS animations are a bit challenging for me to grasp, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I'm open for a new markup structure if necessary.

My code: https://codesandbox.io/s/2v85nk?file=/src/TextSlider.js

The desired effect: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bDVqeulKpwFyDKA9sKqxduR7OFgBZKK0/view?usp=sharing

I attempted to modify these two lines within .slider-item, making some progress but not quite reaching the desired outcome.

```
.slider-item {
  opacity: 0.5; // Added to show the previous item slightly while transitioning
  transform: translateY(-100%); // Altered scrolling direction
}
```

Comment: Hi, The element moving in to view seems good to me. Maybe you just need to make the old element out of view to produce scrolling effect. Is that all or you think there is something else to make it more like desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use scroll [snapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type). Explanation in comments.

```js
// give nudge to trigger scroll snap
function flick(e) {
  // scroll back up if reached end
  if (e.scrollHeight - e.scrollTop - e.clientHeight < 1) {
    e.scrollTop = 0;
  }
  e.scroll({
    top: e.scrollTop + 51,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
  setInterval(flick, 2000, slider);
});
```

```css
.slider {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;

  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: flex;

  scroll-snap-align: center;
}


/* cosmetics */
.item * {
  margin: auto;
}

.item:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.item:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="item"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>4</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>5</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>6</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>7</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>8</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>9</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>1</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, tho it wasn't what i was quite aiming for.

Comment: I see. I didn't read the problem well. Updated the solution.

Comment: Thanks for that, love your simple approach to it. The code really speaks for itself

Answer (score 2):

The new element appearing in view seems to work fine. But to make is more like desired effect you need to show old element moving out of view smoothly.

First thing if you need transition on `opacity` as well add it to `.slider-item` class. You can add transitions for multiple property :

```css
.slider-item{
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
}
```

`.slider-item` keeps the element below and out of visible area.

`.slider-item.active` brings it into visible area.

Now just add class `.slider-item.prev-active` class that will move the element above and out of visible area. This should be added to element whose `index == currentIndex -1`. There however is a catch with using this condition as is. After a full round - The `(texts.length -1)th` element won't move out because `currentIndex - 1` is -1 at this point.

I modified this condition a bit to work well when the index becomes 0 after a full round:

```
(index + 1) % texts.length === currentIndex
```

The css class:

```css
.slider-item.prev-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

The class can be added as :

```
className={`slider-item ${index === currentIndex ? "active" : ""} 
           ${(index + 1) % texts.length === currentIndex ? "prev-active":""`}
```

Full code :

```js
const root =  document.getElementById("root")
const {useState, useEffect} = React;
const TextSlider = ({ texts }) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % texts.length);
    }, 2700);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [texts.length]);

  return (
    <div className="text-slider">
      {texts.map((text, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className={'slider-item '+ (index === currentIndex ? "active" : "") +  ((index + 1) % texts.length === currentIndex ? "prev-active" : "")}>
          <h1 style={{ fontSize: "92px" }}>{text}</h1>
          <img
            style={{ aspectRatio: "1/1", width: "86px", borderRadius: "6px" }}
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/1e/Troye_Sivan_-_Bloom_%28Official_Album_Cover%29.png"
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const texts = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text 5"];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Text Slider</h1>
      <TextSlider texts={texts} />
    </div>
  );
};



ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    root
);
```

```css
.text-slider {
  height: 100px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.slider-item.prev-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.slider-item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<body id="root"></body>
```